# How to express Rust lifetimes for a function that returns a generic, borrowing iterator

Tags: rust

I want to have a function in a struct that takes in a state and returns an iterator. That is working so far unless I want the iterator to borrow from the state, which should be fine but I can't figure out how I would express the lifetimes.

This is a minimal reproduction of the code in question. The first example works fine because the `Vec` is cloned but I don't want to clone for performance reasons.

```rust
use std::fmt::Display;

struct State {
    items: Vec<i32>,
}

struct HasIteratorFunction<T: Display, I: Iterator<Item = T>> {
    iterator: Box<dyn Fn(&State) -> I>,
}
impl<T: Display, I: Iterator<Item = T>> HasIteratorFunction<T, I> {
    fn print_items(&self, state: &State) {
        for item in (self.iterator)(state) {
            println!("{}", item);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    // this works
    let it = HasIteratorFunction {
        iterator: Box::new(|state| state.items.clone().into_iter())
    };
    it.print_items(&State { items: vec![1, 2, 3] });
    
    // this doesn't
    let it_without_cloning = HasIteratorFunction {
        iterator: Box::new(|state| state.items.iter())
    };
    it_without_cloning.print_items(&State { items: vec![4, 5, 6] });
}
```

The real code will be even more generic so returning a slice instead of a generic iterator won't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement something like that, but not with closures, and not exactly as requested (note I added `copied()`):

```rust
trait HasIterFn {
    type Item;
    type Iter<'a>: Iterator<Item = Self::Item>;
    fn get_iter<'state>(&self, state: &'state State) -> Self::Iter<'state>;
}

// A shortcut for where the iterator is not borrowing.
impl<F: Fn(&State) -> I, I: Iterator> HasIterFn for F {
    type Item = I::Item;
    type Iter<'a> = I;
    fn get_iter(&self, state: &State) -> I {
        self(state)
    }
}

struct HasIteratorFunction<T: Display, I: HasIterFn<Item = T>> {
    iterator: I,
}
impl<T: Display, I: HasIterFn<Item = T>> HasIteratorFunction<T, I> {
    fn print_items(&self, state: &State) {
        for item in self.iterator.get_iter(state) {
            println!("{}", item);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    // this works
    let it = HasIteratorFunction {
        iterator: |state: &State| state.items.clone().into_iter(),
    };
    it.print_items(&State { items: vec![1, 2, 3] });
    
    // this doesn't
    let it_without_cloning = HasIteratorFunction {
        iterator: {
            struct Func;
            impl HasIterFn for Func {
                type Item = i32;
                type Iter<'a> = std::iter::Copied<std::slice::Iter<'a, i32>>;
                fn get_iter<'state>(&self, state: &'state State) -> Self::Iter<'state> {
                    state.items.iter().copied()
                }
            }
            Func
        }
    };
    it_without_cloning.print_items(&State { items: vec![4, 5, 6] });
}
```

In the future, you may be able to implement this better and maybe without `copied()`, but currently, due to how the `Fn` traits are designed and constraints of the type system, IMHO this is the best you can get.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an explicit lifetime to `State` in the callback you store in your `HasIteratorFunction` struct and adding a lifetime bound to `I` for the same lifetime works for your example:

```
use std::fmt::Display;

struct State {
    items: Vec<i32>,
}

struct HasIteratorFunction<'a, T: Display, I: Iterator<Item = T> + 'a> {
    iterator: Box<dyn Fn(&'a State) -> I>,
}
impl<'a, T: Display, I: Iterator<Item = T> + 'a> HasIteratorFunction<'a, T, I> {
    fn print_items(&self, state: &'a State) {
        for item in (self.iterator)(state) {
            println!("{}", item);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let state = State { items: vec![1, 2, 3] };
    
    // this works
    let it = HasIteratorFunction {
        iterator: Box::new(|state| state.items.clone().into_iter())
    };
    it.print_items(&state);
    
    let state = State { items: vec![4, 5, 6] };
    
    let it_without_cloning = HasIteratorFunction {
        iterator: Box::new(|state| state.items.iter())
    };
    
    it_without_cloning.print_items(&state);
}
```

[Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1e1a50fd5630717cb6678b622861f883)

Comment: This breaks the original `it.print_items(&State { items: vec![1, 2, 3] });`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to be able to modify state between calls of `print_items`. I tried something like this already and it borrows state for the whole lifetime of `HasIteratorFunction`. I feel more and more like this isn't even possible to express with rust lifetimes.

Comment: @cafce25 My bad, I added the first example with the cloning to my snippet. You have to bind `State` to some variable to make it work, otherwise a temporary value is created that is dropped immediately.